# Should I use “/dev/random” or “/dev/urandom” for large random data needs?

Tags: linux, random-number-generator

Sometimes I want a lot of highly-random data, for example to overwrite a file or even a whole hard disk. Should I use [`/dev/random`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random) or [`/dev/urandom`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/urandom.4.html)? What are the advantages or disadvantages of each? Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For large amounts of data, you need to use `/dev/urandom`. The `u` is for "unlimited", meaning that there will always be data available. If you try to read a lot of data from `/dev/random`, it will block, preventing your program from continuing for a while.

Both [`/dev/random`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random) and [`/dev/urandom`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/urandom.4.html) provide unpredictable (random) data. The data from `/dev/random` is intended to be *completely* unpredictable (or *truly random*), making it suitable for things like long-term cryptographic keys (where an attacker in the future may have the advantages of extensive research and much faster computers to try and break the algorithm used to generate the data). The data from `/dev/urandom` is based on truly random data, but may be run through a high-quality *pseudo-random* function to produce additional data. It is still suitable for things like encryption keys, as long as you don't need to be sure they won't be broken for decades, but can also be used for bulk data.

The Linux kernel maintains an "entropy pool" of unpredictable data, wherein each bit has an equal chance of being true or false (one or zero). The kernel builds this entropy pool from various inputs, such as hardware sources, drivers, user actions, and anything else that cannot be reliably predicted. However, these sources take time to accumulate entropy, so the entropy pool can be depleted if it is consumed too quickly.

`/dev/random` draws directly from the entropy pool. When the pool is depleted, reading from `/dev/random` doesn't return any more data until the pool has refilled enough, which can take quite some time. `/dev/urandom` uses a [cryptographically-secure pseudo-random number generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) (CSPRNG) seeded from the entropy pool. It can generate an infinite amount of output, but the output cannot be predicted without knowing the internal state of the CSPRNG. Because the internal state is initially based on truly-random data, and the CSPRNG algorithm used is designed to not leak its internal state through its output, `/dev/urandom` is still a good source of highly-random data.

To recap, when you need *maximally* random data, use `/dev/random`. However, if you need a lot of data, you need to use `/dev/urandom`. In general, use `/dev/urandom` unless you need the data to be indistinguishable from truly random noise for decades to come.

Comment: I thought the u stood for `unblocked`, but that's a detail. Good answer!

Comment: Wikipedia claims "unlimited", with a citation of the kernel function [`random_read_unlimited`](http://repo.or.cz/w/davej-history.git/blob/d0562c8dc:/drivers/char/random.c#l682), but "unblocked" makes perfect sense as well. According to the manpage, you can't actually get more than 32MB out of `/dev/urandom` in a single read anyhow.

Comment: I always assumed the u was for unsigned, like uint is an unsigned int in many languages. Very informative, thanks